# Get the smallest float larger or equal to a double (and the largest smaller or equal) in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, double, rounding

I'm making an acceleration structure (BVH) out of double precision 3D objects. For being more memory efficient, I would like the BVH to be in float precision. But I need for this the following functions:

- Get the lowest float higher or equal to a double
- Get the highest float lower or equal to a double

Does these functions exist in standard c++? (c++11)

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, use `std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()` and a cast (or implicit conversion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in function.  Some quick experimentation shows
that:

```
float fLower = d;
float fUpper = d;
if ( fLower < d ) {
    fUpper = nextafterf( fUpper, FLT_MAX );
} else if ( fUpper > d ) {
    fLower = nextafterf( fLower, -FLT_MAX );
}
```

seems to work with g++; in my small trial, I didn't find it
necessary, but more generally, you might need to use the 
`-ffloat-store` option, at least if optimization is turned on.

One point worth mentionning, however: The `nextafter` functions
were only added to C++ in C++11, and are not generally supported
as C++ functions (e.g. `std::nextafter` after including
`<cmath>`).  *If* the compiler also supports C99 (as g++ does),
then you can probably find them by including `<math.h>`, and by
treating them as C functions.  Including calling `nextafterf`,
as I did above, rather than depending on function overload
resultion to find a `float` version of `nextafter`.  And if,
like Microsoft, the compiler doesn't support C99, they may not
be present at all.  (They aren't present in VS 2012, for
example.)  Given this, your safest solution might be to get the
sources for the gcc C library, and extract the bit of code you
need.  (Note that IIUC, you'll have to put your code under GPL
if you do this.)

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. I'm using gcc but I'd like to keep the code portable, so as looking into gcc libc source will give only one implementation anyway, I may end up decomposing the float mantissa/exponent and do the work myself, which is not more portable but not GPL restricted

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're looking for the [`nextafter`/`nexttoward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter) functions.

You still have to build some logic around this, but that should give you the building block needed to "step through" representable values.

---

Maybe (untested) try something like this:

```
float get_float(double d)
{
    long double const x = d;

    for (float f1 = d, f2 = f1; ; f2 = f1)
    {
        f1 = std::nexttoward(f2, x);
        if (f1 == f2) { return f1; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it?  None of these seem to correspond to what he's looking for: given a `double` (exact value), he wants the two floats (which may be the same) which best frame it.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Wouldnt that work by converting from double to float, then you are on one side, and with after/toward you get one step to the other side?

Comment: @JamesKanze: The functions can be used to obtain the desired value after converting the double to float.

Comment: After rounding double d to float f1, test for f1==d. If so, done. If not, the other bound is nexttoward(f1,d).

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: That's not so easy, since you can only compare two things of the same type. But you can go back to double and take advantage of the fact that doubles can represent floats (at least on IEEE754).

Comment: @JamesKanze: I think if you use version (5) (`float(float, long double)`) in a loop until the argument doesn't change, you should have it, give or take one step.

Comment: @KerrekSB If they exist, they can be convenient in the implementation of the actual solution (although the function you want is, I think, `nextafter`).  (FWIW: `std::nextafter` isn't present in VC++ nor in g++.  G++ does have the C versions, however.)

Comment: @KerrekSB After studying it a bit, I think that `nexttowardf` would work (without any need of a loop); it would avoid the `if` in my solution.  On the other hand, you wouldn't know which of the two `float` was above, and which below, without testing them for order.